# pop integers from the deque using threads

Tags: python, multithreading

i tired to do this four day but still stuck on it
Please help me to solve this threads question.

The program on next slide has 2 threads running a producer and a
consumer. They communicate through a deque.

• The producer writes integers 0 , 1, 2, ... and 9 to the deque.

• The consumer tries to pop integers from the deque to build a list. But
numbers are missing randomly from the list. For each omitted number, there
is a pop error message printed.

Modify the program so that there will not be pop errors anymore and all
integers are present in the output list.

```
import time
import threading
import random
from collections import deque

def int_producer(n, d):
    for i in range(n):
        time.sleep(random.random()/10)
        d.append(i)

def int_consumer(n, d):
    my_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        time.sleep(random.random()/10)
        try:
            my_list.append(d.popleft())
        except IndexError:
            print("pop error")
    print(my_list)

def main():
    d = deque(maxlen=3)
    threads = [threading.Thread(daemon=True, target=int_producer,
                                args=(10,d)) for i in range(3)]
    threads.extend([threading.Thread(daemon=True, target=int_consumer,
                                    args=(10,d)) for i in range(3)])
    [thread.start() for thread in threads]
    [thread.join() for thread in threads]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

here are my code

```
import time
import threading
import random
from collections import deque

def int_producer(n, d):
    global has_space, has_full 

    for i in range(n):
        time.sleep(random.random()/10)
        with has_full:
            while len(d) == 3 :
                print ( ' wait here ' )
                has_full.wait()
        with has_space:
            d.append(i)
            has_space.notify()


def int_consumer(n, d):
    global has_space, has_full 

    my_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        time.sleep(random.random()/10)
        try:
            with has_space:
                while len(d) == 0 :
                    has_space.wait()


            with has_full:
                while len(d) == 3 :
                    has_full.notify()


            my_list.append(d.popleft())    


        except IndexError:
            print("pop error")
    print(my_list)

def main():
    global cv, has_space, has_full 
    has_full = threading.Condition()
    has_space = threading.Condition()

    d = deque(maxlen=3)
    threads = [threading.Thread(daemon=True, target=int_producer,
                                args=(10,d)) for i in range(3)]
    threads.extend([threading.Thread(daemon=True, target=int_consumer,
                                    args=(10,d)) for i in range(3)])
    [thread.start() for thread in threads]
    [thread.join() for thread in threads]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the result is like, which the list should be [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

```
[0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7]
[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
[0, 1, 1, 4, 4, 6, 9, 8, 9, 9]
```

Comment: so you have given us the code you were given in your homework, but what have you tried to solve the issue?

Comment: Are you allowed to swap out `deque` for the inherently thready `queue.Queue()`?

Comment: are you expecting 3 lines of output or a single line? cause you are starting 3 producers and 3 consumers so your outputs will still be mixed.

Comment: expecting 3 lines to conform each thread can output right result -> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: @AKX it must use deque